# Java Frame extract values of actionPerformed() to save it

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

I'm programming my first GUI in Java Language and I have found an problem/issue.

This is my code:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    public void init() {

        // Paneles

        JPanel Frame1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel Buttons = new JPanel();
        JPanel Principal = new JPanel();

        JLabel jlName = new JLabel("Nombre");
        JLabel jlPbm = new JLabel("PBM");
        JLabel jlYears = new JLabel("Año");

        JTextField jtName = new JTextField();
        JTextField jtPbm = new JTextField();

        TabCalc TableR = new TabCalc();

        JComboBox<String> Years = new JComboBox<>();
        Years.addItem("");
        Years.addItem("2019");
        Years.addItem("2020");
        Years.addItem("2021");
        Years.addItem("2022");
        Years.addItem("2023");
        Years.addItem("2024");

        jtPbm.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                try {
                    Integer PBMd = Integer.parseInt(jtPbm.getText());
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Frame1, "¡Ingresa un PBM válido!", "Error!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    jtPbm.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        JButton buttOK = new JButton("Enviar");

        buttOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String pbmGot = jtPbm.getText();
                String yearGOt = Years.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if (pbmGot.equals("") || yearGOt.equals("")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Principal, "¡Información incompleta!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(pbmGot) > 100 || Integer.parseInt(pbmGot) <= 0) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Principal, "¡Información errónea!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    } else {

                        DBConnect sql = new DBConnect(pbmGot, yearGOt);
                        ArrayList<Object> s = sql.ConnectDB();
                        boolean x = (boolean) s.get(0);
                        if (x == true) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Principal, "¡La consulta fue exitosa!", "Aviso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        /*
         * String pbmGot = "23";
         * String yearGOt = "2023";
         * 
         * TableR.tabFill(pbmGot, yearGOt);
         */

        JButton buttDel = new JButton("Borrar");
        buttDel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jtName.setText("");
                jtPbm.setText("");
                Years.setSelectedItem("");
            }
        });

        Buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 2, 5));
        Buttons.add(buttOK);
        Buttons.add(buttDel);

        Frame1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2, 5, 2));
        Frame1.add(jlName);
        Frame1.add(jtName);
        Frame1.add(jlPbm);
        Frame1.add(jtPbm);
        Frame1.add(jlYears);
        Frame1.add(Years);

        Principal.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Principal.add(Frame1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        Principal.add(Buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        Principal.add(TableR, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(Principal);

        setTitle("Calculadora de matrícula");
        setSize(400, 300);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui1 = new GUI();
        gui1.init();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the text inside JTextField jtPbm and JComboBox Years to pass to tableFill method that is outside of addActionListener method of JButton.

How I get those values? Thanks!

Note: The code I type is only a part of the complete code.

Comment: Perhaps try an declare `jtPbm` and `years` as *class member* variables, for example: `private JTextField jtPbm; private JComboBox<String> years;` (use proper naming). Then *when* initializing these variables within the **`init()`** method do: `jtPbm = new JTextField();` and `years = new JComboBox<>();`. These components should now be in scope anywhere in class.

Comment: @DevilsHnd, It works! But, there's another problem. I want to show a table (JTable) in the panel when user enters information and press the buttOK, so when code runs buttonOK is added and it is obtained value of pbmGot and yearGot which are null, so there will be an error. I could move that part of the code inside actionPerformed method of Jbutton, but I need to get that panel and this method is void. So can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Declare `pbmGot` and `yearGot` and class member variables as well so that their scope is class global as well. On a side, in code, you had spelled `yearGot` as `yearGOt`.

Comment: @DevilsHnd OK, I just made the changes in the code. There is an error, I just debugged the code and tabFill method receive null parameters, I think because user will press button when GUI is created, while this happens, the method doesn't receive parameters even when it is called.

Comment: Cool...All working now?

Comment: @DevilsHnd No, the method tabFill isn't receiving parameters (`pbmGot`, `yearGot`) even when they're declared as class members. Could it be because method is called during code execution?

Comment: @DevilsHnd I think calling of the method `tabFill` should be inside the method  `actionPerformed`, so that when button is pressed `tabFill` will be executed with parameters that are received from ActionListener. Inside of conditional, I type `TableR.tabFill(pbmGot,yearGot)` and `Principal.add(TableR)`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @DevilsHnd I just try to put `TableR.tabFill(pbmGot,yearGot)` and `Principal.add(TableR,BorderLayout.CENTER)` and `Principal.updateGUI()` and it works!